# Symfony 5 Reset Password how do i get the right url?

Tags: symfony, reset-password

I'll try to explain my problem.
I have recently started a new projet and wanted to implement a reset password functionnality.
Everything seems to work except the generation of the url which is send by email.

[picture of my URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e56Y.png)

My URL should look like this : http://localhost/projectName/public/reset-password/reset/xOdfPc0iGC7nmReqX02jcemgX4EIlt2tb5vNYgTZ

But the "/projectName/public/" is missing.

I don't understand what i did wrong.
Here is my twig template for the email :

```
<h1>Bonjour !</h1>

<p>Pour réinitialiser votre mot de passe, merci de vous rendre sur le lien suivant</p>

<a href="{{ url('app_reset_password', { token: resetToken.token }) }}"> {{ url('app_reset_password', { token: resetToken.token }) }}</a>

<p>Ce lien expirera dans {{ resetToken.expirationMessageKey|trans(resetToken.expirationMessageData, 'ResetPasswordBundle') }}.</p>

<p>A bientôt !</p>
```

Here is the function in the controller that generates the templated email :

```
private function processSendingPasswordResetEmail(string $emailFormData, MailerInterface $mailer, TranslatorInterface $translator): RedirectResponse
    {
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy([
            'email' => $emailFormData,
        ]);

        // Do not reveal whether a user account was found or not.
        if (!$user) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_check_email');
        }

        try {
            $resetToken = $this->resetPasswordHelper->generateResetToken($user);
        } catch (ResetPasswordExceptionInterface $e) {
            // If you want to tell the user why a reset email was not sent, uncomment
            // the lines below and change the redirect to 'app_forgot_password_request'.
            // Caution: This may reveal if a user is registered or not.
            //
            // $this->addFlash('reset_password_error', sprintf(
            //     '%s - %s',
            //     $translator->trans(ResetPasswordExceptionInterface::MESSAGE_PROBLEM_HANDLE, [], 'ResetPasswordBundle'),
            //     $translator->trans($e->getReason(), [], 'ResetPasswordBundle')
            // ));

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_check_email');
        }

        $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from(new Address('assistance@asintel.com', 'AS Intel - Assistance'))
            ->to($user->getEmail())
            ->subject('Your password reset request')
            ->htmlTemplate('reset_password/email.html.twig')
            ->context([
                'resetToken' => $resetToken,
            ])
        ;

        $mailer->send($email);

        // Store the token object in session for retrieval in check-email route.
        $this->setTokenObjectInSession($resetToken);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_check_email');
    }
```

And this is the function with app_reset_password route :

```
/**
     * Validates and process the reset URL that the user clicked in their email.
     *
     * @Route("/reset/{token}", name="app_reset_password")
     */
    public function reset(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher, TranslatorInterface $translator, string $token = null): Response
    {
        if ($token) {
            // We store the token in session and remove it from the URL, to avoid the URL being
            // loaded in a browser and potentially leaking the token to 3rd party JavaScript.
            $this->storeTokenInSession($token);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_reset_password');
        }

        $token = $this->getTokenFromSession();
        if (null === $token) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('No reset password token found in the URL or in the session.');
        }

        try {
            $user = $this->resetPasswordHelper->validateTokenAndFetchUser($token);
        } catch (ResetPasswordExceptionInterface $e) {
            $this->addFlash('reset_password_error', sprintf(
                '%s - %s',
                $translator->trans(ResetPasswordExceptionInterface::MESSAGE_PROBLEM_VALIDATE, [], 'ResetPasswordBundle'),
                $translator->trans($e->getReason(), [], 'ResetPasswordBundle')
            ));

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_forgot_password_request');
        }

        // The token is valid; allow the user to change their password.
        $form = $this->createForm(ChangePasswordFormType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // A password reset token should be used only once, remove it.
            $this->resetPasswordHelper->removeResetRequest($token);

            // Encode(hash) the plain password, and set it.
            $encodedPassword = $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                $user,
                $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
            );

            $user->setPassword($encodedPassword);
            $this->entityManager->flush();

            // The session is cleaned up after the password has been changed.
            $this->cleanSessionAfterReset();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('main_index');
        }

        return $this->render('reset_password/reset.html.twig', [
            'resetForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Does someone have an idea what i should do to fix this problem ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show the code where you define your `app_reset_password` route? Ideally please use Code Sample formatting to share your code rather than pictures

Comment: Hello Hugo, thanks for your response and advice. I edited my question to show the code you asked for. Have a good day